# Apple rejecting my app saying content does not load in ipv6 network

Tags: ios, alamofire, appstore-approval

I've been trying to get my application approved in the app store for quite some time now. Each time apple rejects it saying they could not load content in ipv6 network.

To start with, I am from Nepal and the isp here does not provide ipv6 support till now in our connection.
I have made some friends in Canada and USA as my external testers, and my app is working smoothly there. As Apple suggested, I created a virtual ipv6 hotspot from my mac mini, and the content is loading nicely here in Nepal too, but they keep say its not loading when they try to review. So what is up with apple review team, i did all the things they suggested.

I am using Alamofire 3.4.1 for networking, and researched abit to find out, Almofire surely is ipv6 complaint.

I really need the app in app store soon.  Any insight would be really appreciated.

Comment: Use the 2 free Code-Level Support came with your developer membership to solve this will be your best bet. You'll get direct help from an Apple engineer with code. You can find it via https://developer.apple.com/account/#/support/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test iOS app is it supporting IPv6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096725/how-to-test-ios-app-is-it-supporting-ipv6)

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai I was planning to do so too. But will apple be viewing my code? and what if they give me other problem with my code, saying this and that. Will they do so?

Comment: They can't view your code unless you provide them. You can create a sample project for the support to see, or ask them directly what you should do regarding the question above.

Comment: don't use ip address like: 10.0.0.1, use domain name: abc.com may work

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution though I don't know if its the best practice or not, but my app got accepted. All I did was added a single character in NetworkReachabilityManager class of alamofire.

```
public convenience init?() {
    var address = sockaddr_in()
    address.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(address))
    address.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let reachability = withUnsafePointer(&address, {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }) else { return nil }

    self.init(reachability: reachability)
}
```

changed line

```
address.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
```

to

```
address.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET6)
```

Do let me know, if there might be some issue by doing this.